# why Stream Reader Add \b\b in commands in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, streamreader, arp

stream reader adds new line when i use this command:

```
 run show arp interface ge-0/0/4.7600 | match 09:7f:de:f2:E1:22
```

I get an error due to \b\b\b\b\b\b\b added. The response  is:

```
farouk#run show arp interface ge-0/0/4.7600 | 
farouk# ...ge-0/0/9.1100 | m                      atch 
09:7f:de:f2:E1:22

farouk#  ...h 9:7f:de:f2:E1:                     22
```

the command must be in same line to get data
but it adds a new line after |

my code :

```
string cmd="run show arp interface ge-0/0/4.7600 | match 09:7f:de:f2:E1:22";    
var client = new SshClient(IP, Port, Username, Password))               
client.Connect();               
var sh= client.CreateShellStream("atrem", 300, 800, 800, 600, 3072);  
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sh);               
sh.WriteLine(cmd);    
Thread.Sleep(3000);      
string line="";
line = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

how i can solve it?

Note:the response is IP corresponding to sent Mac Address

and \b\b\b is match a backspace

Comment: What is the variable that doesn't have the value that you expect? What is the value that you expect?

Comment: `I get an error due to new space added.` What is the error? Where is the new space added? What is the value of `line`?

Comment: but the command is write as farouk#run show arp interface ge-0/0/4.7600 | new line

Comment: the response is IP corresponding to sent Mac Address

Comment: I don't know `SshClient`, but I assume what you're _reading_ is the response, and the newline isn't added by the `StreamReader`, but was already part of that response.

Comment: the response it IP but it add \b\b\b\b\b\b\b between commands

Comment: AFAIK the `\b` character is the character used to represent backspaces, so most likely these characters are in fact part of the actual response you're getting / reading (or they are added by the `SshClient`, but I kind of doubt that). The `StreamReader` is definately not adding anything to the underlying stream. Have you tried checking the actual response using some other SSH client?